# How do I make a responsive div change height depending on its content?

Tags: html, css, responsive

```css
.data {
        margin: 80px 60px 0px 80px;
        position: relative;
        background-color: #BEBDC3;
        border-radius: 5px;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        justify-content: space-between;
        height: 400px;
        width: 70%;
    }
    
    .dataispod {
        background-color: #ffffff;
        border-radius: 5px;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        height: 400px;
        width: 100%;
    }
    
    .slikacontainer {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        overflow: hidden;
        width: 50%;
    }
    
    .slikawrap {
        height: 80%;
        width: 80%;
        background-size: contain;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-position: center;
        border-radius: 5px;
        border: none;
        filter: url('#filter-radius');
    }
    
    @media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
    
    .data {
        margin: 20px 60px 30px 60px;
        position: relative;
        background-color: #BEBDC3;
        border-radius: 5px;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        min-height: 300px;
        min-width: 50%;
        margin-bottom: 150px;
    }
    
    .dataispod {
        background-color: #ffffff;
        border-radius: 5px;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        min-width: 100%;
        min-height: 300px;
    }
    
    @media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
    .slikacontainer {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        overflow: hidden;
        width: 100%;
        min-height: 200px;
        justify-content: flex-start;
        align-items: center;
    }
    
    .slikawrap {
        height: 80%;
        width: 80%;
        background-size: contain;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-position: left;
        border-radius: 5px;
        border: none;
        filter: url('#filter-radius');
        margin-left: -20px;
    }
    }
```

```html
    <div class="data">
    <div class="dataispod">
    <div class = "detaljilevo">
        <div class="detaljilevosub">
            [... some content ...]
        </div>
    
        <div id="buttonwrapperdetalji">
            [... some other content ...]
        </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="slikacontainer">
        <div class="slikawrap" style="background-image: url('../slike/<?=$podaci->slika?>')"></div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

I'm trying to use the minimum height of the div so the content would determine its size, but it doesn't seem to be working. The height is fine when it doesn't have a picture inside, but when it's displaying a post with a picture, it's partly outside of the div. Can someone point me in the right direction?

[image: Image of the div]

Comment: Please add some more suitable content to your HTML. Currently your code hardly can visualize the problem.